# Conversion to special characters (example from "&aelig;" to "æ")

Tags: c#

I want to save files which will have name with danish characters, for example "Helloæ".

The string which saves the filename has this value: `Hello&aelig;`

How to make it convert `&aelig;` to `æ` ? This question isn't just about the "æ" characters, but for all other possible letters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&aelig;` is the HTML encoding of `æ`. Thus, you need to HTML-*decode* your string.

[HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) does exactly that:

```
var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Hello&aelig;");  // yields Helloæ
```